# NSLog delay-general question?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i use NSLog many times,and i know that it has a delay time .
my app has a delay time ,and i wonder if many logs can create that.

for example, if i have this code :

```
samplerTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.001f target: self selector: @selector(CheckData) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
NSLog(@"%f",tmp);
```

the timer is calling a function each 1ms,and it works great, but my concern is that the log takes more time so the timer routine kind of change.
i use hardware,so mseconds are important.

i am trying to understand,what exactly happen during nslog? the system is sleeping? other things are done in parallel ?
how much time exactly does it take ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSLog()` writes to the standard output or error using `printf`. It will also cause a flush, meaning that the program blocks until the output has been sent to the OS. This is slow.

Removing the `NSLog()` statements will speed things up a lot. The easiest way to turn all logging off, is adding:

```
#define NSLog(...) 0
```

in your prefix header (the `.pch` file), **below** the framework includes. Or you could add this line in the files you want to silence. If effectively replaces all `NSLog()` statements with `0`, which does nothing.